# Using this keyword on constructor's parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, tslint, tsconfig

```
name: string;

constructor(private value: string) {
  this.name = value;
  // or 
  this.name = this.value;
}
```

Which of these options are better. Why have I an option to use `this` prefix on `value`? Is it valid to use `this` keyword on constructor's parameters?

I've used an `noUnusedParameters`, `noUnusedLocals` in tsconfig and tslint to make sure that there is no unused variables in my program. Unfortunately tslint reports constructor's parameters if there is no `this` before them (marks them as unused which is weird).

Comment: Won't `this.value` be `undefined`?

Comment: Are you sure? http://jsbin.com/natamanuta/edit?js,console

Comment: @evolutionxbox your jsbin link is javascript, the question is asking about typescript. See the `private` keyword? Makes all the difference.

Comment: @Duncan putting in `private` outputs JS which uses `this.value = value` first. It seems to be pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this.value` because you are assigning it when you declare it in the constructor with an access modifier as `private value: string`.

If you do not intend to use `value` in other functions, it is better to just inject it, without giving it and access modifier.

```
name: string;

constructor(value: string) {
  this.name = value;
}
```